# Why doesn't the plus operator overload work for strings in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, operator-overloading

I was able to achieve an operator overlay for my class, but I can't achieve it for String in any way. Why?

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    String.metaClass.plus = {
        r -> return "-";
    }

    print "left" + "right"
}



//I tried and so:
static void main(String[] args) {
    String.metaClass.plus = {
        r -> return "-".toString();
    }

    print "left".toString() + "right".toString()
}
```

[Example from Groovy online compiler](https://onecompiler.com/groovy/3zhztkcyv)

**Update.**

I managed to achieve the desired result. I just added the String type to the anonymous function parameter.

```
//Old - non-working version.
String.metaClass.plus = {
    r -> "-";
}

//New - working version.
String.metaClass.plus = {
    String r -> "-";
}
```

The question remains the same, why didn't the old version work and the new one works? In the lesson that I'm watching, everything works well, ChatGPT also said that everything should work.

Comment: ChatGPT is rubbish for subtle questions such as this. And usually subtly wrong for everything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy already has
[`plus`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#plus(java.lang.CharSequence))
overloaded (the behaviour you are seeing).

Your version `String.metaClass.plus = { "-" }` implies this version:
`String.metaClass.plus = { Object it -> "-" }` (by default groovy
closures have a default single argument `it`, which is of type `Object`
(or `def` in groovy-speak).

So now there are two `plus` on String and the JVM picks the best match,
when calling it (polymorphism at work)... which is not yours, because
`Object` is more generic than `CharSequence` for your example arguments.

So you *can* force your version like this:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    String.metaClass.plus = { "-" }
    print "left" + 42 // ⇒ -
}
```

Forcing the type of the argument to `String` -- like you did in your
working example -- makes your function now the chosen one, when called with
a `String` argument (and maybe any argument, because Groovy might coerce).

Note beside:

Writing closures like

```
{
    String r -> "-"
}
```

is extremely misleading to the reader.  Arguments are usually kept in
the line with the opening brace.

```
{ String r -> 
    "-"
}
```